# How does Doctrine create a table in MySQL for me?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I've now read kinda half of the Doctrine 2 documentation but I can't find a solution: how do I create a table for a class automatically using Doctrine?

Do I really need to work with XML/YAML or some other stuff than PHP itself? Do I really need DQL for that? Doesn't Doctrine find the names and all this stuff for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to understand that in Doctrine 2 there are three elements that play together:

- entities (just plain PHP classes)
- mappings (additional markup that you place on entities or in related classes)
- database

Doctrine reads your entities and your mappings and connects every entity and its fields to the related database fields.

The generation of the database is done by the `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool` ([SchemaTool](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.php)) class, which can read metadata and define how your schema should like.

Doctrine's CLI, as said by @Marcin, provides the `orm:schema-tool:create` and `orm:schema-tool:update` commands, which are just wrappers for the `SchemaTool`. They help you getting started fast and keep your schema in sync with your entity definitions.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, that helps a little bit. But i now get the following message when trying to run orm:schema-tool:create on the Mac OS X Lion Terminal: "PHP Warning:  PDO::__construct(): [2002] No such file or directory (trying to connect via unix:///tmp/mysql.sock) in /usr/lib/php/pear/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 36"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly.
If you want to create a structure in a database, use the console function [`orm:schema-tool:create`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/tools.html)